# from the bites of it, any ideas if it's rats or squirrel

Tags: fruit-trees, rodents

All the fruits are being eaten up by rats/squirrels. Please help identify

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would put my money on birds .Squirrels for sure leave nothing but pits, I think rats are the same. You should notice happy birds such as robins ,hanging around.

Comment: While I don't have a lot of experience with birds eating fruit, when they've eaten from our nectarines, they'd do holes that looked similar to slug bites, and usually only a little bit per fruit. There's quite a bit of that peach that's been eaten.